# Problem with my initialize

Tags: jquery

could someone help me with this please, for some reason on page load the buttons all seem to be in the "on" position even though i have one checkbox "checked" and the other not checked.

The problem seems to be in the if/then of the initialize_slideCheck(). I guess I am misusing the next()???

How can I target only the .checkboxTrigger that is wrapped in the same div as the checkbox?

[PAGE LOCATED HERE](http://www.getstefan.com/learning/onoff.htm)

Any help appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                function initialize_slideCheck(){
                    var slideCheck = $('.slideCheck');

                    slideCheck.wrap("");
                    slideCheck.after("");

                    slideCheck.attr('style', 'display:block;');

                    if(slideCheck.is(':checked')){
                        $(this).next(".checkboxTrigger").css("left", "-8px");
                    }else if(slideCheck.not(':checked')){
                        $(this).next(".checkboxTrigger").css("left", "-40px");
                    } 

                }

                initialize_slideCheck();

                $(".checkboxTrigger").click(function(){

                    var position = $(this).position().left;

                    if(position == -8){
                        $(this).animate({"left": "-40px"}, 200);
                        $(this).prev('.slideCheck').attr('checked', '');
                    }
                    else if(position == -40){
                        $(this).animate({"left": "-8px"}, 200);
                        $(this).prev('.slideCheck').attr('checked', 'checked');
                    }

                });

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. `is()` returns `true` if *any* of the elements in the set match the selector. In this case, the ':checked' condition will always eval to true.

```
function initialize_slideCheck() {
    $('.slideCheck')
        .wrap("<div class='checkboxWrapper rounded'></div>")
        .after("<a class='checkboxTrigger' href='#'></a>")
        .css({'display':'block'})
        .each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if ( $this.is(':checked') ) {
                $this.nextAll('.checkboxTrigger').css({'left':'-8px'});
            } else {
                $this.nextAll('.checkboxTrigger').css({'left':'-40px'});
            }
        })
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also, your click handler on the checkboxTrigger element does not 'check' the checkbox correctly. Replace `.attr('checked', '')` with `.attr('checked', false)`

Comment: Wow Mr. Cowie thank you very much for the help, it worked! im sure by looking at my code you can tell that I am new to this, I didnt even know that we could stack .wrap, .after etc one on top another like that. Just looking at your code shows me just how far I am from being a programmer, Thanks again!

Comment: @user548906 No problem. jQuery is easy when you get the hang of it. Stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

`next()` selects the next sibling. Use `nextAll('selector')` instead. You can check the complete manual on `nextAll()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/). Same happens with `prev()`. Use `prevAll()` instead. You can read that manual [here](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried nextAll and am still having no luck. I have updated the OP with a link to the example page I am working on, do you think you could take a quick peek?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell for sure without seeing the HTML, but it looks to me that the problem is with your $(this).next(...) method calls within the initialize_slideCheck method. At this point **this** is the document, so next() will not get the element next to slideCheck. I think what you are probably trying to do is:

```
function initialize_slideCheck(){
    ...
    if(slideCheck.is(':checked')){
        slideCheck.next(".checkboxTrigger").css("left", "-8px");
    } else if(slideCheck.not(':checked')){
        slideCheck.next(".checkboxTrigger").css("left", "-40px");
    }
}
```

Note the change from $(this).next to slideCheck.next.

Comment: Hmm I gave this a shot and still no dice, I have updated the OP with a link to the page I am working on, could you please take a quick peek?  Disregard the CSS, its just to show the checkbox that will be hidden once this thing works correctly.